# Partial Derivative and Differentiability

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I need help for the following question.

Do the partial derivatives of the function $f(x, y)=min(|x|,|y|)$ exist and what are they?

Also, I don't think the function is differentiable at $(0,0)$ but how should I prove this from definition?

Many thanks!

Comment: Recall that you can write the minimum of two variables, say $x$ and $y$ as: $\textrm{min}(x,y) = \frac{x+y-|y-x|}{2}$

Answer (score 1):

Keeping in mind that $\frac{d}{dx}\vert x\vert=\frac{x}{\vert x\vert}$ and that

\begin{equation}
f(x,y)=\vert x\vert \text{ for } \vert x\vert<\vert y \vert
\end{equation}

and

\begin{equation}
f(x,y)=\vert y\vert \text{ for } \vert x\vert>\vert y \vert
\end{equation}

we conclude that

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\frac{x}{\vert x\vert},\,\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=0 \text{ for }\vert x\vert<\vert y \vert
\end{equation}

and

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=0,\,\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=\frac{y}{\vert y\vert} \text{ for }\vert x\vert>\vert y \vert
\end{equation}

Note that both partials are discontinuous for $\vert x\vert=\vert y\vert$.